# Text on Button is not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, controltemplate

I have styled my `Buttons` in the `Windows.Resources` tag. Everything is working fine, except for the `Content`, it is not displayed.

```
<Window …>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#989898"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0E121A" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
       …
       <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Send"
                        Click="ButtonActivateLicense_OnClick" />
    </Grid>
<Window>
```

Comment: Your style overrides the default template but does not use a template binding for the content, so where should it be rendered if you does not specify it?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/style-button-in-wpf/ on how you could style a button

Comment: Ensure it has enough height (or set `.Padding` to `0`)

Answer (score 1):

As you override the default template for `Button`, you also have to specify an element to display the content. You can simply add a `ContentPresenter` to your `Border` to display the content.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#989898"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
               <ContentPresenter/>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0E121A" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Alternatively, add an element and use a [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.templatebindingextension?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.TemplateBindingExtension);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) to bind the content, e.g.:

```
<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

From the documentation of [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.templatebindingextension?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.TemplateBindingExtension);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0):

> Implements a markup extension that supports the binding between the value of a property in a template and the value of some other exposed property on the templated control.

Of course, if you use a different control like `TextBlock` and bind the content to e.g. `Text`, you should be aware that only text will be displayed correctly, not any type of content.

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```